# What is differece between insampleSize and compress in Android webview?

Tags: android, capture

As I searched about this topic in Google, 
1.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            if (bitmap == null) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
            }
```

It means the file pixel is reduced like 1000*1000 to 300*300.
and

2.

```
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bos);
```

It means the size(file volume) is reduced like 1000kb -> 800kb.

Is it right? 
Because... when I upload some images, if the file is big, i failed to upload. (I checked the file volume is reduced by 2nd way, not 1st way)

so I try 1st way but also fail. but when i try 2nd way, I got success!!

so That's the reason why I ask this question.

C.f> 
If i cropped bitmap, the bitmap is changed???

```
    Bitmap croppedBitmap = null;
        if (i!=cnt) {
            if ((croppedStart + pageHeight) > webview.getMeasuredHeight()) {
                int lastHeight = webview.getMeasuredHeight() - croppedStart;
                croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, croppedStart, webview.getMeasuredWidth(),lastHeight-1);
            } else {
                try{
                croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, croppedStart, webview.getMeasuredWidth(), pageHeight);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            croppedStart += pageHeight;
            rtn.add(croppedBitmap);
        }
```

after I do this, my bitmap(orginal) is changed fullBtimap to Last croppedBitmap.
also  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quality works only lossy format like jpeg and affects the [quality of the image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_quality). `inSampleSize` requests to subsample the original image. It affects both width and height, meaning that the final image will be `1/inSampleSize` smaller, in width and height of the original

Comment: hm.. Dose the insampleSize make subsample... ?? It means If I control or give insampleSize option, the original bitmap is not resized??

sorry ...I don't understand exactly... could u explain more detail..?

Comment: inSampleSize subsamples the original bitmap. E.g. if you give inSampleSize = 2, the bitmap will be width/2 and height/2 of the original

Comment: ah really?? omg. Thanks!! it is really helpful. so I have another question, On the other hands, the compress option is not changed?? Is it only related on volume?

Comment: it is related only to `width` and `height`. Remember that you need `width*height*4` bits to keep a bitmap in memory.

Comment: oh!? useful Information.  so that`s the reason why the app is oom. right? Thanks.

Comment: that could be a reason